# Can i format without authentication password? if so how?

Tags: linux, formatting, password-recovery

got a used laptop running Ubuntu cant upgrade or format without authenticate password that i don't have also i'm not used to using Linux systems

Comment: have you tried booting from a live-CD and formatting the disk from it rather than the running system? or you could consider reinstalling the OS, since you don't know the password you need and the computer will be much less usable without it.

Comment: yes it says the hard-drive has no free space even though its basically 100% free

Comment: Certainly if you boot to an installation environment, delete all partitions, then a password is no longer required.  Additionally, I seem to remember, it trivial to reset the root password of my Ubuntu VM years ago.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the system prompts you for an authorization password before letting you perform an action, you must enter the password.

If you do not know the password then you should not be performing the action on this system.

If you believe you should be authorized, you should speak to the person responsible for the computer.